# Compile error in eclipse for c++

Tags: c++, eclipse

First of all, I'm new to Linux OS.

I installed `ubuntu` and `eclipse` and the `c/c++` package.

I started a new project, that is the default project, "Hello World c++ project",
and when I run it, it's given me the erorr:

```
Description     Resource    Path    Location    Type
Program "g++" not found in PATH         Preferences, C++/Build/Settings/Discovery, [CDT GCC Builtin Compiler Settings] options  C/C++ Scanner Discovery Problem
```

What should I do?

Comment: I am having the same issue, were you able to fix it ?? Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

Try to install all developer tools typing in console: `sudo aptitude install build-essential`. It will install g++, gcc and all libraries.

Comment: I get this error: sudo: aptitude: command not found. I run it in  the Terminal

Comment: Maybe try `sudo apt-get install build-essential`. These are similar programs, I don't know differences.

Comment: `apt-get` isn't working or still you have the same problem with no g++ found?

Comment: I have the same problem with no g++ found

Comment: @Nir If you have ubuntu, try update repositories [repos](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) than update and restart your system. How did you istall `eclipse` and other packages? You can install eclipse from repositories or download it from [eclipse home](http://www.eclipse.org). You can also try to install `build-essential` using **Ubuntu Software Center**.

Comment: I install the eclipse and the packages using Ubuntu Software Center. build-essential installed.

Comment: @Nir I'm not sure, but if it's eclipse, maybe it needs java installed: [how to install java](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-ubuntu-12-04.html).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Here's how I fixed it:

1. Run sudo `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to install the gcc, g++ and libraries.
2. Update the PATH environmental variable in the `/etc/environment` file adding `/usr/bin/g++`
3. Restart your VM or PC for this changes to take effect.